# Удаление класса родителя при нажатии на дочерний элемент

Tags: jquery

Есть вот такая разметка

```
<div class="list">'
 <div class="m">1</div>
 <div>2</div>
 <div>3</div>
 <div>4</div>
</div>
```

Изначально `.list div:not[class="m"] {display: none;}`, но при нажатии на `.list` этот класс получает ещё один класс, допустим `.active`.
А `.acive div {display: none !important;}`

JQ выглядит примерно так

```
$('.list').on('click',function(){
 $(this).addClass('.active');
});
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на див с классом **m**, удалялся класс **active**, с учётом того, что подобных "списков" (list), может быть несколько и чтобы остальные не "откликались".

---

Пытался сделать так:

```
$('.list').on('click',function(){
 var $nav = $(this);
 $nav.addClass('active');
 $(this).find('.m').on('click',function(
  $nav.removeClass('active');
 ));
});
```

Но это не работает в принципе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on("click", "div.list div.m", function(){
  $(this).closest("div.list").removeClass('active');
});
```